# Event Listener Not Firing on Second Button in DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've placed two buttons in a div, each with an event listener that carries out a different function. The first works fine, however, the second does not fire. It doesn't even seem to recognise that it's a button as the cursor does not change automatically on mouseover. Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const startBtn = document.getElementById('start');
const restartBtn = document.getElementById('restart');
const formContainer = document.getElementById('input-container');

startBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  formContainer.classList.replace('hidden', 'visible');
});

restartBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  resetGame();
});

const resetGame = () => {
  players = [];
  playerShips = [];
  computerShips = [];
  gameboard.playerArea = new Array(100).fill(false);
  gameboard.computerArea = new Array(100).fill(false);
  playerInterface.innerHTML = '';
  computerInterface.innerHTML = '';
  formContainer.classList.replace('hidden', 'visible');
};
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 30%;
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="start-area fade-in">
    <h1>BATTLESHIP</h1>
    <p>Start the game below!</p>

    <button id="start" class="visible btn">Start Game</button>
    <button id="restart" class="hidden btn">Restart Game</button>
  </div>

  <div id="input-container" class="hidden">
    <form id="user-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter player name" id="form-input" name="name">
      <button type="submit" id="user-submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

When clicking the `id='restart'` button, the `resetGame` function shown above is supposed to fire (this function exists in a `gameflow` module in another file).

Comment: shouldn't you call resetGame instead of gameflow.resetGame?

Comment: in `restartBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  gameflow.resetGame();
});`

where is `gameflow` defined ?

Comment: A word of caution about using fat arrow syntax with event listeners : https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: **Always** check the console for errors.  Address those first, like: "Uncaught ReferenceError: gameflow is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gameflow` object with `resetGame()` method does not exist. Therefore the line `gameflow.resetGame();` throws exception. Replace the line with `resetGame();` and the function will be called.

Note, the following objects is not defined too:

- `gameboard`;
- `playerInterface`;
- `computerInterface`.

Fix the mistakes and it should work.

If you assert the `gameflow.resetGame()` method is defined in another file, make sure the file is included (see [`src`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp) attribute of the `script` element) to the page, loaded, and the method is accessible. To check the method open browser console and try to call it.

Comment: Sry for the lack of context everyone. Please assume that all missing variables are defined. The gameboard and gameflow modules are defined in other files. This was paraphrased code.

Comment: @Genetic1989, make sure the files are loaded (see resources tab in development tools) and the variables are accessible from the code.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice everyone. Turns out, the margins were preventing the button from being clickable in the document flow. Changing the location of the button to a new, absolutely positioned div did the trick

Answer (score 0):

The `e.preventDefault()` bit is mainly just for submit buttons. Try taking that out of your regular buttons.